# Determine an Eigenbasis given a characteristic polynomial with only two different roots

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be an endomorphism given by $f(x)=Ax$, in which 
$$
A=\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
 {-6} & {2} & {-1} \\
 {2} & {-3} & {-2} \\
 {-1} & {-2} & {-6}
\end{array} \right)
$$
The characteristic polynomial is 
$$
\chi_{f}(t)=(-7-t)^{2}(-1-t)
$$
Determine an Eigenbasis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ for $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.**

*How is this possible when there is only two different roots $\lambda_1 = -7$ and $\lambda_2=-1$* ? I could not find any useful theorem or corollary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to find the eigenvectors? Here it's $-7$ that is the multiple root. If you solve the system $(A+7I)x=0$, you get the matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&-1\\ 2&4&-2\\ -1&-2&1\end{bmatrix} 
$$
Row reduction quickly gives you 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&-1\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So $ x_1+2x_2-x_3=0$. If you take $x_2,x_3$ as a parameters $s,t$, you get $x_1=-2s+t$. Thus the solutions are 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2s+t \\ s\\ t
\end{bmatrix} 
=s\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\ 1\\ 0
\end{bmatrix} 
+t\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0\\ 1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
That gives you two linearly independent eigenvectors for $-7$.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to determine the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $-7$, you will get that they are the linear combinations of $(1,0,1)$ and $(-2,1,0)$. Since $(-1,-2,1)$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$,$$\bigl\{(1,0,1),(-2,1,0),(-1,-2,1)\bigr\}$$is an eigenbasis.

Comment: How do one show that the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue -7 is a linear combination of (-2,1,0) and (-1,-2,1)?

Comment: That's not true. What's true is that every eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-7$ is a linear combination of $(1,0,1)$ and $(-2,1,0)$. Since these two vectors are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $-7$, every linear combination of them is also an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-7$. And if the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue $-7$ was larger than that, it would have to have dimension $3$ at least and therefore it would have to be the whole $\mathbb R^3$.